# Not able to install pack on stackstorm HA(K8)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've been trying to install custom pack using these links on a single node K8 cluster.

https://github.com/StackStorm/st2packs-dockerfiles/

https://github.com/stackstorm/stackstorm-ha

Stackstorm is installed successfully with default dashboard but when I tried to build custom pack and helm upgrade it's not working.

Here is my stackstorm pack dir and image Dockerfile:

```
/home/manisha.tanwar/st2packs-dockerfiles # ll st2packs-image/packs/st2_chef/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x. 4 manisha.tanwar domain users 4096 Apr 28 16:11 actions
drwxr-xr-x. 2 manisha.tanwar domain users 4096 Apr 28 16:11 aliases
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 manisha.tanwar domain users  211 Apr 28 16:11 pack.yaml
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 manisha.tanwar domain users   65 Apr 28 16:11 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 manisha.tanwar domain users  293 Apr 28 17:47 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 manisha.tanwar domain users 4096 Apr 28 16:11 rules
drwxr-xr-x. 2 manisha.tanwar domain users 4096 Apr 28 16:11 sensors
```

/home/manisha.tanwar/st2packs-dockerfiles # cat st2packs-image/Dockerfile

```
ARG PACKS="file:///tmp/stackstorm-st2"
FROM stackstorm/st2packs:builder AS builder

COPY packs/st2_chef /tmp/stackstorm-st2/
RUN ls -la /tmp/stackstorm-st2
RUN git config --global http.sslVerify false

# Install custom packs
RUN /opt/stackstorm/st2/bin/st2-pack-install ${PACKS}

###########################
# Minimize the image size. Start with alpine:3.8,
# and add only packs and virtualenvs from builder.
FROM stackstorm/st2packs:runtime
```

Image is created using command
`docker build -t st2_chef:v0.0.2 st2packs-image`

And then I changed values.yaml as below:

```
  packs:
    configs:
      packs.yaml: |
        ---
        # chef pack
    image:
      name: st2_chef
      tag: 0.0.1
      pullPolicy: Always
```

And run 
`helm upgrade <release-name>.`
but it doesn't show anything on dashboard as well as cmd.

Please help, We are planning to upgrade to Stackstorm HA from standalone stackstorm and I need to get POC done for that.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with the help of community. Here's the link if anyone want to follow:

https://github.com/StackStorm/stackstorm-ha/issues/128

I wasn't using docker registery to push the image and use it in helm configuration.

Updated values.yaml as :

```
  packs:
    # Custom StackStorm pack configs. Each record creates a file in '/opt/stackstorm/configs/'
    # https://docs.stackstorm.com/reference/pack_configs.html#configuration-file
    configs:
      core.yaml: |
        ---
    image:
      # Uncomment the following block to make the custom packs image available to the necessary pods
      #repository: your-remote-docker-registry.io
      repository: manishatanwar
      name: st2_nagios
      tag: "0.0.1"
      pullPolicy: Always
```